# WPF MVVM update status while processing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, enums

I'm working with a validation signalized by enum states in WPF MVVM. The validation is triggered by the click of a button. 
This is the enum and the code of the command:

```
public enum StatusTest {None, Ok, Error, Processing }

public ICommand TestConnectionCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_testConnectionCommand == null)
            _testConnectionCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () => this.Test());

        return _testConnectionCommand;
    }
}
void Test()
{
    Status = StatusTest.Processing;
    if ( ValidationMethod()) Status = StatusTest.Ok;
    else Status = StatusTest.Error;
}
```

Next to the button I have a circle, linked with the enum StatusTest that has changed your fill with the status change.
    Currently it only displays the final status (ok or error), never processing. How do I get the circle to be filled by the color processing during the validation process?

Comment: If status is updating to show ok or error then most likely the process is just completing fast enough that it doesnt show processing.  Can you put a delay in your validation method and see what happens?

Comment: i put a 5 seconds delay
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears all your work is on UI thread so the first setter of Status does not take effect. Change you code to below to let Test() work on a different thread.

```
public enum StatusTest {None, Ok, Error, Processing }

public ICommand TestConnectionCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_testConnectionCommand == null)
            _testConnectionCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () => ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Test));

        return _testConnectionCommand;
    }
}
void Test(object state)
{
    Status = StatusTest.Processing;
    if ( ValidationMethod()) Status = StatusTest.Ok;
    else Status = StatusTest.Error;
}
```